# Create two aggregate columns by Group By Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm new to DataFrames and I want to group multiple columns and then sum and keep a count on the last column. e.g.

```
s = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix([[1, 2,3,4], [3, 4,7,6],[3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,7]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  3  4  7  6
2  3  4  5  6
3  1  2  3  7
```

I want to group on `a`, `b` and `c` but then sum on `d` and count the elements within the group. 
I can count by

```
s = s.groupby(by=["a", "b", "c"])["d"].count()

    a  b  c
    1  2  3    2
    3  4  5    1
          7    1
```

And I can sum by

```
s = s.groupby(by=["a", "b", "c"])["d"].sum()

a  b  c
1  2  3    11
3  4  5     6
      7     6
```

However I want to combine it such that The resulting dataframe has both the sum and count columns.

```
    a  b  c   sum    count
    1  2  3    11     2
    3  4  5     6     1
          7     6     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html), or shorter version `agg`:

```
print (s.groupby(by=["a", "b", "c"])["d"].agg([sum, 'count']))
#print (s.groupby(by=["a", "b", "c"])["d"].aggregate([sum, 'count']))
       sum  count
a b c            
1 2 3   11      2
3 4 5    6      1
    7    6      1
```

[Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once).

The difference between `size` and `count` is:

[`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) counts `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not.

If need count `NaN` values also:

```
print (s.groupby(by=["a", "b", "c"])["d"].agg([sum, 'size']))
       sum  size
a b c           
1 2 3   11     2
3 4 5    6     1
    7    6     1
```